# Sorting of Date ArrayList

Tags: java, android, sorting

I have an `ArrayList` which contains dates with a format (Satuday,4 Februray 2012). How can I sort this `ArrayList` ?

Comment: What have u done ? to do so ?  have u tried ?

Comment: what class are you using for your dates?

Comment: In which kind you need to start either day or date or year?

Comment: Dates with a format? Do you mean the dates are stored as strings? Because `java.util.Date` objects do not have a format by themselves.

Comment: I tried using Collections.sort()....I have four to five date items in array list in the format "Saturday,4 Februray 2012"...I have to sort them to display in a order by latest to older one.

Answer (score 23):

This is one of the Simplest way to sort,

```
Collections.sort(<Your Array List>);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have any special requirements while sorting, so you may do it by providing your own `Comparator`. For example:

```
//your List
ArrayList<Date> d = new ArrayList<Date>();

//Sorting
Collections.sort(d, new Comparator<Date>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Date lhs, Date rhs) {
        if (lhs.getTime() < rhs.getTime())
            return -1;
        else if (lhs.getTime() == rhs.getTime())
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }
});
```

The key element is that you are converting your `Date` object into **milliseconds** (using `getTime()`) for comparison.

Comment: Else just use Collections.sort(<Your Array List>); as @Aerrow said. Dates are [comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)).

Answer (score 5):

After 8 years..

```java
List<Date> dates = datelist;
List<Date> sorted = dates.stream()
  .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(Date::getTime))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```