# How to order date along with in-order time in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sorting, kotlin

I'm working on a side project and trying to sort the dates stored in the list.

I have String list containing the information bellow:

```
calendarEventTime ["28/04/2021 06:00 p.m.", 
                   "28/04/2021 10:00 a.m.",
                   "29/04/2021 05:00 p.m.", 
                   "28/04/2021 05:45 p.m.", 
                   "29/04/2021 08:00 a.m.", 
                   "29/04/2021 04:00 a.m."]
```

Want the result to be:

```
calendarEventTime ["28/04/2021 10:00 a.m.",
                   "28/04/2021 05:45 p.m.",
                   "28/04/2021 06:00 p.m.", 
                   "29/04/2021 04:00 a.m.",
                   "29/04/2021 08:00 a.m.",
                   "29/04/2021 05:00 p.m."]
```

I did Collections.sort(list) that works well for the first part but doesn't arrange it considering the time.

I will really appreciate if someone will help me out, thanks!!

Comment: This may answer your question. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561396/sorting-of-date-arraylist)

Comment: It's important what data type your dates are - can you provide a code snippet?

Comment: I rephrased the question I hope you can help me out!

Comment: Damien Hunter I checked out the link but that is for the dates format (Satuday,4 Februray 2012) :(